# How to access an object's public fields from a Velocity template

Tags: java, field, velocity, public, vtl

Here is my object class:

```
public class Address
{
    public final String line1;
    public final String town;
    public final String postcode;

    public Address(final String line1, final String town, final String postcode)
    {
        this.line1 = line1;
        this.town = town;
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }
}
```

I add it to the velocity context like this:

```
Address theAddress = new Address("123 Fake St", "Springfield", "SP123");
context.put("TheAddress", theAddress);
```

However, when writing the template, the following will not render the address fields (however, it works fine when I add getters to the Address class)

```
<Address>
    <Line1>${TheAddress.line1}</Line1>
    <Town>${TheAddress.town}</Town>
    <Postcode>${TheAddress.postcode}</Postcode>
</Address>
```

Is it possible to access public fields on objects from Velocity without adding getters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not by default.  You need to configure a different Uberspect implementation.

Comment: Could you add any details such as link to documentation on how to do this or on why this is neccessary?

Comment: It's necessary because Velocity doesn't support public fields.

Try this out: http://maven-doccheck.sourceforge.net/samples/ShinobuDemo/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/introspection/PublicFieldUberspect.html

Comment: It's brilliant that they implement their framework according to convention rather than actual language rules...

Answer (score 4):

The [Velocity user guide](https://click.apache.org/docs/velocity/user-guide.html) suggests it's not possible. Quote:

> [Velocity] tries out different alternatives based on several established naming conventions. The exact lookup sequence depends on whether or not the property name starts with an upper-case letter. For lower-case names, such as $customer.address, the sequence is

1. getaddress()
2. getAddress()
3. get("address")
4. isAddress()

> For upper-case property names like $customer.Address, it is slightly different:

1. getAddress()
2. getaddress()
3. get("Address")
4. isAddress()

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/VelocityFAQ:

> Q: How can i access my object's public fields in my templates?
>
> A: Currently, you have three options:
>
> - Wrap your object with a [FieldMethodizer](http://jakarta.apache.org/velocity/docs/api/org/apache/velocity/app/FieldMethodizer.html)
> - Configure your VelocityEngine to use a custom uberspector like the [PublicFieldUberspect](http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/PublicFieldUberspect)
> - Lobby the velocity-dev list to add public field introspection as a default fallback if no matching method is found :)

`FieldMethodizer` works only with public static fields.

`PublicFieldUberspect` example code is quite old and it just fails with error on nonexistent fields.

And forget about lobby at dev list.)

---

Meanwhile, there is good caching [implementation](https://github.com/apache/velocity-engine/blob/trunk/velocity-engine-core/src/main/java/org/apache/velocity/util/introspection/UberspectPublicFields.java) of [UberspectPublicFields](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/util/introspection/UberspectPublicFields.html) in current [velocity trunk](https://github.com/apache/velocity-engine). Unfortunately, there was [no active development for years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469211/is-apache-velocity-still-an-active-project) and no plans for next release are published.
One would have to build it himself and bundle in private repository.

---

Another altervative is a fork with bonus scala compatibility that is available in central maven repository:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sksamuel.scalocity/scalocity/0.9.

Drop in instead of usual velocity dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sksamuel.scalocity</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalocity</artifactId>
  <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Then just add to `velocity.properties`:

```
runtime.introspector.uberspect = org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectPublicFields, org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl
```

The caveat is that `UberspectImpl` is patched with additional support for scala properties and requires 8 MB scala jar.

---

Eventually, I just interned the following classes from velocity trunk into own project:

> org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.PublicFieldExecutor
> org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SetPublicFieldExecutor
> org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.ClassFieldMap
> org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.Introspector
> org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.IntrospectorBase
> org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.IntrospectorCache
> org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.IntrospectorCacheImpl
> org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectPublicFields

These work fine with Velocity 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

i do

```
import org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl;
import org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectPublicFields;

....

properties.setProperty("runtime.introspector.uberspect",
  UberspectImpl.class.getName() + ", " +
  UberspectPublicFields.class.getName());
```

And all works OK!!!