# velocity template when object is not null , need to replace with extra string

Tags: java, velocity

I create one text message i.e.

"vishal is working as developer, since $obj.object[0].timeStamp"

if timeStamp is null then String should replace with

"vishal is working as developer"

So I tried like 
"vishal is working as developer, #if ($obj.object[0].timeStamp) , since $obj.object[0].timeStamp" #end

it is not working please help me out

Comment: "it is not working" is not an error description. Please show the error message. If there is an exception then show the full stack trace. If there is no error, what is the output?

Comment: I could suggest to check this link :https://wiki.apache.org/velocity/CheckingForNull

Answer (score 0):

Have you got getters? 
Please read this: [How to access an object's public fields from a Velocity template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068607/how-to-access-an-objects-public-fields-from-a-velocity-template)

If I were you maybe I would pass the $obj.object[0].timeStamp to the velocity not only the $obj. (Especially if you need only this value from the object)

Finally for checking the null I think soorapadman's answer is perfect.